# Receiving data on XBee module on a XBee explorer from a XBee module on an Arduino

Tags: arduino, communication, xbee

I've a network formed by:

A: XBee S2 module mounted on an Arduino UNO using a XBee shield v1.1, configured as Zigbee router/end device AT mode.

B: XBee S2 module mounted on a XBee explorer conntected to a PC with XCTU software, configured as Zigbee coordinator AT mode.

I uploaded the following code to Arduino. As you can see, A is waiting to receive data. When A receives data, starts to send data to B, and B receives it.

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  establishContact();
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println('A'); // It is shown in B
    delay(2000)
}

void establishContact() {
  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.readString(); // Read data from B
}
```

**Problem:**

If Arduino runs the following code, A sends data to B before receiving any data from it, then B doesn't receive data (no led blink) from A.

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println('A'); // It isn't shown in B
    delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using xbee A in API mode? Please specify what data are you sending to B. 
As far as I have heard and read, you need to connect xbee in API mode to MCU, not AT mode. you can refer to the book - "Building Wireless Sensor Networks" by Robert Faludi for your purpose.